# Running a long running function in a MVC Controller Asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with Asp.net MVC 4, and I'm trying to have a function run in the background when the user clicks a link on a page.

I have searched and searched, and I cannot figure out what to do.

The function I am trying to run is a function inside the `PhoneNumbersController`, and it doesn't return anything, it just does a lot of work.

Basically the user inputs a list of phone numbers (a very LARGE amount of numbers) and then clicks go.

The server will then save all of those phone numbers to a DB. Then I want the server to run a function similar to this:

```
    Foo(int accountId)
    {
        var account = GetAccountById(accountId);

        while (account.IsRunning)
        {
            var Number = (from n in account.PhoneNumbers
                          where n.Status = "new"
                          select n).FirstOrDefault();
            // Do some work on Number.

            Thread.Sleep(1000); // I'm working with an API that limits you to 1 per second.

            account = GetAccountById(accountId);
        }
    }
```

I know, that code is terrible, but it's just to show an example.

I'm going to be running through possibly at least 100,000 numbers, so we have to be able to pause and resume this (hence the while(IsRunning) variable. I have a pause function that will set that value to false.

As someone who's never worked with asynchronous requests or multithreading before, what would be the best option here, and how would I go about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at Async/Await ?

Comment: I've looked into it, but it's all way over my head at this point. In my head I feel like there should just be a way to say "Run this function in the background asynchronously", and it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: Using async you can add multi threaded power to a single request but every async will be finished by the time you return the response

Comment: Yeah, I'd like it to continually run in the background, freeing up the user to do whatever while it is running.

Comment: By a `pause` function, do you then mean some `ActionResult` that sets the `IsRunning` flag to `false`? - If that's the case, how do you ensure thread safety, and that the value is up to date (flushed to memory)?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** : Reading the comments below, this solution seem only appropriate for short tasks, since application pool may kill created thread

You could simply create a background thread:

```
var t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Foo(yourAccountId)) {IsBackground= true};
```

And run it :

```
t.Start();
```

Comment: Doesn't ASP.net recycle the application pool if it is not in the middle of serving a page? I don't think this will work as his thread will just be killed without warning if the recycle happens

Comment: Every time I tried something like that, I got a syntax error, but I'm not getting one this time. haha I'm trying it out now. Thanks!

Comment: @CharliePugh I would wait for confirmation for or against my concerns. It may work right now but you may see "random" bugs when IIS decides to recycle your app pool in the middle of your processing. Almost [every question asking about this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ASP+long+running) the answer was "*don't do the long running process in your ASP.net app, have a 2nd external service that does the long running operation and use some form of IPC to communicate between them (like [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx))*"

Comment: I aggree with scott to t(h)read carefully :) If the thread will finish in about a minute i would follow your approach. But if it can run for up to 10 minutes i would not trust the application pool to keep it alive for that long.

Comment: I'm wanting to run this for a lot longer than a couple minutes. haha Is there any way I could maybe have the request bounce between different functions to avoid timeout?

Comment: Then i would suggest making some sort of queue(either a real queue or just a table where you write some data). Then write a service that runs non stop to listen to this queue system or write a console app that you shedule periodicly. If it has to be real time you need to look into something service ish like wcf but for me that would be a last solution.

Comment: @Kristof Why a second process? As long as the queue is persisted somehow (db), any processing can be done from within the web app in a background thread which can be restarted, if needed, after the app is recycled by IIS. Not pretty but doable.

Comment: @bkdc if unused for a while the application pool could fall asleep. Having a second process ensures that the thread is alive, will require less resources because it's not an iis thread and it is just a bit simpler imho :)

Comment: I tried it but it crash when HttpContext is deleted ;( Any idea how to start proces which will continue when for example user close page?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would not be nessecary to spawn a new thread for this within an ASP.NET website. Each client request is handled in a thread of the ISS.

However if the process is really taking too much time away from the web server, which i doubt. You could always delegate the real work to another system.

Comment: True, but if you don't want your browser to hang while server is processing a very very long request, creatng a thread is an option

Comment: No the browser will always have to wait till the server returns a response. Having a new thread being spawn on the server will not solve a thing here

Comment: Why not. The thread is spawn, then controller returns a response, and browser displays the page while thread is still running on the server

Comment: @Kek, that's what I was thinking too, but nothing I've done has gotten that to work.

Comment: Kek and his solution are correct though. Try it out, starting a new thread will not stop your browser from receiving a response even if the thread is not finished. The thread will continue to work untill it is either finished or destroyed by the application pool.

Comment: Ah, yes i see, your right the thread would keep running in the background. However i would not advise it. I would rather go for a solution where a message will be send via for example msmq to a windows service handling the actual work request. I don't feel confident about keeping a background thread alive after the original thread which did the request has died.